# For a simple key-value pair list JSON, use jq to print only key-value pairs where value is greater than a given constant number

Tags: jq

Consider the following JSON having a list of key-value pairs

```
{
  "session1": 128,
  "session2": 1024,
  "session3": 258,
  "session4": 128,
  "session5": 32456,
  "session6": 128
}
```

The key is a session identifier, and the value is the length of the value stored in the session.

**FYI** - The above JSON is created with the following

```
cat session_detail.json | jq '.[]' | jq -c 'with_entries(.value |= length)' > session_len.json
```

I want to print only those key-value pairs where value > 128.

The expected output is

```
{
  "session2": 1024,
  "session3": 258,
  "session5": 32456
}
```

I have tried to use **select**.

Comment: Why isn't `"session3": 258` included? Otherwise this would simply be `with_entries(select(.value > 128))`. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xL8FXorjcpp)

Comment: But as you are using `with_entries` anyways, it'd probably work to just include the new `select` therein. Try `.[] | with_entries(.value |= length | select(.value > 128))`.

Comment: @pmf That was an oversight. I have edited the post to include `"session3": 258`

Comment: @pmf I would like to keep them separate. The `session_len.json` is meant to have lengths of **all** keys. The filtered one is meant to show keys where the length is greater than a certain constant. 128 was just an example.

Comment: @pmf  **FYI** Source Redis DB is converted to JSON using [link](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools). Then a separate JSON is created to hold details of the lengths. We are looking into why certain sessions have abnormally large values (length).

Thank you very much for your prompt response. Your answer get me what I was after. So, I would like to accept the first response as the answer.

Comment: If you don't want to connect both filters, then there's no explicit need for `with_entries`. Just use `map_values(select(. > 128))` (or `.[] |= select(. > 128)` which it resolves to) instead (and accept @Philippe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76797247/2158479)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254719/discussion-between-jojo-thomas-and-pmf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map_values together with select :

```
jq 'map_values(select(. > 128))' session_len.json
```

To sort data by numerical value, following seems to work :

```
jq 'to_entries |
    map(select(.value > 128)) |
    sort_by(.value) |
    from_entries' session_len.json
```

(I'm not totally sure if `from_entries` guarantees the order in all cases)

Comment: Thank you for the response and another way. If you don't mind, can you also provide an update for how the data can be sorted by the numeric value.